# Convert 7bit text to plain text perl

Tags: perl, parsing, 7-bit

I parsing email message and i found part with encoding: 7bit
how a can convert text of this part to plain text?
i use perl

Answer (score 1):

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

means that the text is *already* plain old ASCII text.  No conversion is necessary.  (Well, unless the `Content-Type` header indicates a non-ASCII-based charset, but those are pretty rare, especially with 7bit text.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have [UU-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) data (older method) or [MIME-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME). To deal with that, you can use [Convert::UU](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/Convert-UU-0.5201/lib/Convert/UU.pm) and [MIME::Base64](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/MIME-Base64-3.13/) CPAN modules respectively.

To use MIME::Base64 (or its pure-Perl implementation, MIME::Base64::Perl):

```
use MIME::Base64::Perl;
my $decoded = decode_base64($encoded);
```

**How do you know the difference?**

The modern MIME encoded text looks like this (Especially pay attention to `MIME-Version:` header which tells you it's MIME-encoded as well as `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header which tells you the encoding base - if it's not base64, you need a different CPAN module:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="frontier"

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--frontier
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body of the message.
--frontier
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

UU-encoded text would look something like:

```
begin 644 cat.txt
#0V%T
`
end
```

If the encoded data looks differently than either of the above samples, please post the exact format so we can determine what it is.

Comment: i detect different with header Content-Transfer-Encoding
at this time i not support UU-encoded data

Comment: I write my parser which analized message line by line. when i detect boundary i know that next line is header. And i analize this line